# Use multiple databases in a webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services

My question is: I have a web application built using ASP.net and a web service. The web service has to use a different database, depending on which client is logged on.

Is there a easy and elegant solution to do this ?

Comment: what have you tried so far??? it is not suggestion site. try to implement if any problem occurs then ask here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of persistence ignorance?

Comment: I don't know wich one is best to use , thats why i asked it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can check it by passing client credentials in each request to service.
2. Ask client to call init(id,pass,...) method with credentials before calling any web method. You can also ask for optional settings in Init, based on inputs you can give client the access token and let client pass this access token to each request, you can check this access token and parse the settings to take action i.e. to call a particular DB connection. Facebook api works in similar way.